# Car loan out of my name

Tags: loans, car

I bought a car with my father consigning for me. I have been separated from my husband for 18 years. I'm getting the divorce currently and I found out my husband can possibly get the car. Since my dad consigned for the car loan, can he get the car in his name only so my name is off and my husband can't get the car.

Comment: Have the divorce proceedings already started?

Comment: where is the jurisdiction? No country tag so as far as what legal rights you have, it is as much a mystery as what laws are applicable to you. generally speaking if your husband was on the title, then no you can't, if not then you can transfer the title to your father as rightful owning party and remove yourself from it which effectively excludes it as your asset, but as quid said, that depends on whether the process has begun in which case you have to let the process decide who gets what

Answer (score 5):

Ownership and loan co-signing are different things. Just because your father co-signed the loan does not mean he owns any part of the car. You would need to check whose name is on the title. I would expect it to be just you.

In a divorce any and all property is open to division between the partners. However it is unlikely that after eighteen years a car that you presumably bought since then is going to be specifically given to your husband, unless he has been paying for it. Most divorce settlements are by agreement anyway, so it is likely that you could substitute something else for the car.

The only way of absolutely preventing the car (or anything) from being part of the settlement is to sell it or give it away. However doing this and keeping the use of it will likely be seen by any court as an attempt to hide assets and could get you in more trouble.

Presumably you are using a lawyer for the divorce. Talk to the lawyer.